# How do I use ClassPath::getAllClasses in Guava?

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, guava

How do I use [`ClassPath::getAllClasses`](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=GuavaGoogleCoreLibrariesforJava&docset_name=com.google.guava:guava%2023.0&path=dash_javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html%23getAllClasses--&platform=javadoc&repo=Versioned%20Java%20Docsets&version=23.0) in Guava? The following code is the simplest example that I could make. But it just returns an empty collection! I use Guava 23.0 and Eclipse 4.7.2.

```
import com.google.common.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(ClassPath.from(Test.class.getClassLoader()).getAllClasses());
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated from Guava version 23.0 to 24.0, and this fixed the issue. The collection is no longer empty.